# Umbraco Document type field value

Tags: c#, asp.net, umbraco, umbraco7

I'm really new to C# and Umbraco. I need to retrieve the configuration value in my Controller file. Below is the image of my cms and the name it's using is `ApiKeys`

[image]

Now in my controller I want to retrieve the value of `googleMapsApiKey` but I have ZERO knowledge on how to accomplish this. Is there a helper or any class that I need to use to retrieve this? Now this `googleMapsApiKey` is not connected to any particular page meaning I should be able to access this value in any page that I want. Any idea on how to achieve this? Sorry if I can't post any code yet since I have no idea on how to start.

Let's just assume that I want to retrieve the value in one of my function in my Controller. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

First you need to use this Document type (APIKeys in your content tree). 
You can create a node of this content type (APIKeys), then assign a value for the "Google Maps API key" field.

Then, you want to retrieve this value in your C# code or a view.

To do that, you can do something like this:

```
var myAPIKey = UmbracoContext.Content.GetSingleByXPath("//{apiKeysDocumentTypeAlias}").Value<IPublishedContent>("googleMapsApiKey");
```

Replace `{apiKeyDocumentTypeAlias}` with the APIKeys document type alias

I hope this will help you